# PM2 doesn't watch file change at Vagrant machine

Tags: pm2

I set up a server with the following directory structure:

```
project
|-- bootstrap
|   `-- process.json
`-- server
    |-- server.js
    `-- other_folder
```

The `project/bootstrap/process.json` is the PM2 app config file and the `project/server/server.js` is the server entry. I define the `process.json` as

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "odd.server",
      "script": "../server/server.js",
      "watch": "../server"
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to start the server and watch any change in the `server` with the following command:

```
pm2 start process.json --only odd.server --env production
```

The server is up, however, the file watching is not working. Any change made to the `server.js` cannot trigger the restart of the server.

The path is correct and I have no idea on why it doesn't work. I will be grateful to anyone who provides some hint.

UPDATE:

PM2 is running in a Vagrant machine and the `project` folder is a folder of my host machine that is exposed to Vagrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to set the `watch_options` as

```
"watch_options": {
  "usePolling": true
}
```

source: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/931